# milliseconds displayed as 000 in Kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am using Kibana 4.6.2 with Elastic search 2.4.4. But when i see timestamp on kibana dashbaord, milliseconds are always displayed as 000. Can someone please help. I am using this for audit logs and interested in accurate timestamp wih millis?

Comment: It seems like a configuration issue.

Comment: which configuration.. can you please provide details..